# Deployment of Azure Web Site stops existing Web Job

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure Web Site. The site is automatically built and deployed via TFS online (visualstudio.com). The site has `Web Site Mode = Standard`, and `Always On = Enabled`.

I also have a continuous Azure Web Job in the form of a console application. The web job is not included in the automatic deployment. Instead it is updated manually. (Eventually I'm looking to deploy it automatically as well, but not for the moment.)

My web job runs fine, once every minute. I can follow its progress in the job log available on the Azure portal. It can run for several days without problem.

But when I deploy a new version of the web site, the web job stops, and does not start again. Unless you visit the Web Job tab on the Azure portal, then it starts again. (The web job files are not overwritten by the deployment of the web site.)

Why is this? Is there anything I can do to make it not stop, or at least start again once deployment is complete?

Comment: 1. Is this a continuous WebJob or a scheduled WebJob? 2. How do you know it is not working until visiting the WebJobs TAB?

Comment: 1. It's a continuous WebJob. 2. I know it's not working because I can look at a.the data inserted into the database by the WebJob b.the timestamped WebJob log

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a kudu script for this deployment? If you look at the script that is generated with

```
azure site deploymentscript --dotNetConsole
```

There is a call to

```
:: 3. Run web job deploy script
IF DEFINED WEB_JOB_DEPLOY_CMD (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%WEB_JOB_DEPLOY_CMD%" 
)
```

that may kick off the process.

Though if you do already have a kudu script, looking at that generated script file you could copy over the deployment options into you existing script (make sure to have another manifest for the second kudu sync). At that point you could have a consolidated deployment with your push from TFS

Comment: No, I do not have a kudu script. I'm using deployment out of the box by connecting TFS directly from the Azure portal. Do you know if these scripts are runnable from TFS online? (TFS online is somewhat more limited in what you can do during build and deployment, than on-premise TFS.)

Comment: When you deploy to Azure Websites a script will execute on the azure side to perform the deployment. You have the option to provide this script. With the xplat tools 'azure site createdeploymentscript' will get you started with a deployment script.

Comment: The deployment script is not related to TFS. The deployment script runs if you TFS deploy or if you git deploy.

Comment: Interesting! This is totally new territory for me. I could probably get the xplat tools up and running on my local machine in some time. But I don't get how it's connected to the automated deployment. (All articles I find seem to revolve around `Git`, but I'm using `TFVC`.) How do I "provide this script"? Can you point me in the right direction on how to configure Azure to use my custom script?

Comment: Some clarifications: 1. The "WEB_JOB_DEPLOY_CMD" does not start the webjob (it only copies an html file), 2. Since you manually upload the webjob you don't need this deployment script, 3. the deployment script will not run when using TFS, 4. this specific deployment script is for deploying only a .net console application as a single continuous webjob without a website.

Comment: @AmitApple more clarification questions. Can you have a .deployment file with a TFS deployment? After reading some more docs this morning it seems this is bound to git deployment, which seems odd to me. I had thought the deploy command got kicked off when files were made available (whatever their source may be)

Comment: @DennisBurton you can't have .deployment file for TFS deployment, TFS has it's own deployment/build procedures.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is very interesting information, appreciate it! Unfortunately it does not seem to help me, at least not as long as I'm using TFVC.